# How to return list of specific fields in query Java Spring Mongo Repository?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I use Java spring and MongoDB repository in my project.

Here is DTO definition:

```
@Document(collection = "Info")
public class Info  {

  String id,
  Integer count,
  String type
  …
}
```

I need to return from the query a list of IDs where the count field not zero and type filed has 'binary' text.

Here how I try to implement it:

```
@Query(value="{ 'count' : 0, 'type' : 'binary' }", fields="{ 'id' : 1 }")
List<String> getInfo();
```

I get this result from query above:

```
0={"_id": {"$oid": "5eb97a8139d4c62be4d90e4c"}}
1={"_id": {"$oid": "3ec97a8127d4c60cb4d90e9e"}}
```

And I expect this result:

```
{"5eb97a8139d4c62be4d90e4c", "3ec97a8127d4c60cb4d90e9e"}
```

So as you can see I expect to get a list of id strings from the query above.

Any idea what should I change in the query above to get the expected list of ids results?

Comment: Hi Michael, It's not possible with find query, you need to use aggregation to get that result.

Answer (score 2):

**No, that's impossible what you are thinking.**

**Reason :** **MongoDB** can only return **JSON Document**. You can include the fields that you want to be there.

This suggestion that you can follow :

DTO Definition :

```
@Document(collection = "Info")
public class Info  {

  @Id
  private String id;
  
  private Integer count;
  
  private String type;
  
  // other fields and getters and setters
}
```

Sample Repository :

```
public interface InfoRepository extends MongoRepository<Info, String> {

   @Query(value="{ 'count' : 0, 'type' : 'binary' }", fields="{ 'id' : 1 }")
   List<Info> getInfo();
 
}
```

Sample Service class :

```
@Service
public class InfoService {

   @Autowired 
   private InfoRepository infoRepository;

   public List<String> getIds() {
   
      return infoRepository.getInfo()
                      .stream()
                      .map(Info::getId)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());    

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned `{"$oid": "5eb97a8139d4c62be4d90e4c"}` is the [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#bson.ObjectId) representation of an ObjectID.

It is not returning a string because the field stored in the database is of type `ObjectID`, not type `String`.

If you want it to return a string, you should use aggregation with the [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/index.html#tostring-aggregation) operator to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

the best you can get back is a document with an array field with the found ids like this:

```
{
    "ids" : [
        "606018909fb6351e4c34f964",
        "606018909fb6351e4c34f965"
    ]
}
```

which can be achieved with an aggregation query like so:

```
db.Info.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            count: 0,
            type: "binary"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { _id: { $toString: "$_id" } }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            ids: { $push: "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { _id: 0 }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions.

**1. You can use JPA query instead of named query**

```
    public interface InfoRepository extends MongoRepository<Info, String> {
         List<Info> findByCountAndType(final Integer count, final String type);
    }
```

**2. Use java stream api in your business logic to collect all id as List from the above result.**

```
    public class InfoServiceImpl {
       @Autowired
       private InfoRepository repository;

       public String getIds(final String type, final Integer count) {
           return repository.findByCountAndType(count, type)
                  .stream()
                  .map(Info::getId)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{$match: {}} " +
        "{$project: { _id: { $toString: $_id } }} " +
        "{$group: {_id: null, ids: { $push: $_id }}} " +
        "{$project: { _id: 1 }}"})
List<String> getInfo();
```